# Java (beginner): creating a menu that displays features of a calculator

Tags: java

I just started a Java class recently during my associates software engineer track and having difficulty understanding the language.

I need to create a menu that displays the features of a calculator, so the output should display to console like this:

> What would you like to do?
>
> a.) Add two numbers.
>     b.) Subtract two numbers.
>     c.) Multiply two numbers.
>     d.) Divide two numbers.
>
> Please enter a letter.

Then I need to get the choice(input) from the user, grab two numbers(input) from the user.

I don't even know where to begin.  We seriously just started this class and we're diving head first.

Any & all help appreciated!

Comment: When you say you need a menu, you will display it at console?

Comment: Search Google for a basic Java tutorial. If your course doesn't provide you with any reading material, it's not much of a course.

Comment: Yes, the menu needs to display to console.

Comment: If you have absolutely no idea where to start, please have a look at this site here as it will give you some ideas: [Starting Writing a Program](http://www.patriciashanahan.com/beginner.html), the key process being to break the big project down into small steps, and then solving each small step one at a time. If you're still having problems, then you might wish to consider talking to your instructor. Much luck! Voting to close.

Comment: Googled 'Input/output Java' got [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanfor.html). You just need to read a basic I/O tutorial and you're most of the way there. Do your research in future, SO isn't here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Wasn't asking for anyone to complete my homework, just for a nudge in the right direction.  Thank you everyone, you have been most kind.

Comment: It's not a "beginner question"; it's a homework dump, and as such is not up to this site's quality standards. Please go through the [tour], the [help] and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Also have a look at [this stackexchange meta discussion on asking and answering homework questions on this site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class.

For example:

```
java.util.Scanner in = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
String input = in.nextLine();
switch (input.toLowerCase()) {
    case "a":
        System.out.println("Option \"a\" selected;");
        break;
    case "b":
        System.out.println("Option \"b\" selected;");
        break;
```